# Transpose first column of an html table in header

Tags: php

I’m trying to scrape a table on [Borsa Italiana](https://www.borsaitaliana.it/borsa/azioni/global-equity-market/dati-completi.html?isin=FR0000131104)
I use this code

```html
<?php
    $url = "https://www.borsaitaliana.it/borsa/azioni/global-equity-market/dati-completi.html?isin=IT0001477402";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    if($doc->loadHTML($html))
    {
        $result = new \DOMDocument();
        $result->formatOutput = true;
        $table = $result->appendChild($result->createElement("table"));
        $tbody = $table->appendChild($result->createElement("tbody"));

        $xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);

        foreach($xpath->query("//table[@class=\"m-table -clear-m\"]/tbody/tr") as $row)
        {
            $newRow = $tbody->appendChild($result->createElement("tr"));

            foreach($xpath->query("./td[position()>0 and position()<3]", $row) as $cell)
            {
                $newRow->appendChild($result->createElement("td", trim($cell->nodeValue)));
            }
        }
 
    }
echo $result->saveHTML($result->documentElement);
    ?>
```

Result is a table with two columns and more rows. I would transpose first column in header, in order to save result in my database for my personal use.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: there are API's for every stock-market on the planet, why you you scrape like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.borsaitaliana.it/borsa/azioni/global-equity-market/dati-completi.html?isin=IT0001477402";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
if ($doc->loadHTML($html)) {
    $result = new \DOMDocument();
    $result->formatOutput = true;
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
    // collects data in $arr -->
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($xpath->query("//table[@class=\"m-table -clear-m\"]/tbody/tr") as $row) {
        $itm = [];
        foreach ($xpath->query("./td[position()>0 and position()<3]", $row) as $cell) {
            $itm[] = trim($cell->nodeValue);
        }
        $arr[] = $itm;
    }
    // <--
    $table = $result->appendChild($result->createElement("table"));
    // outputs head -->
    $thead = $table->appendChild($result->createElement("thead"));
    $newRow = $thead->appendChild($result->createElement("tr"));
    foreach (array_column($arr, 0) as $th) {
        $newRow->appendChild($result->createElement("th", $th));
    }
    // <--
    // outputs data -->
    $tbody = $table->appendChild($result->createElement("tbody"));
    $newRow = $tbody->appendChild($result->createElement("tr"));
    foreach ($arr as $row) {
        $newRow->appendChild($result->createElement("td", isset($row[1])? $row[1]: ""));
    }
    // <--
}
echo $result->saveHTML($result->documentElement);
```

But I agree with @tim - you have to use [API](https://www.borsaitaliana.it/borsaitaliana/gestione-mercati/bcs-bitclearingstation/bcsapiprogrammersmanual31_pdf.htm) for that.

Comment: Thank You tim and Thank You very much @Jigius, this resolve my problem. I'm a practice and  I don't know how Borsa Italiana's API works. I'm trying to learn it. I took a look to Intrinio, but it's too expensive for me...